# referring to specifically the game theory definition of "game"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need to reference "games" in the context of game theory.

My current sentence is something like "... This method applies for any type of game. For example, this is how it might apply to American Football ..."

I don't want it to come off as whimsical where I'm referring to children's games or sports; it should ideally be a formal, academic tone. The method in question is easiest to exemplify using the example of American Football, so I can't change that. This is for a short, 2 sentence blurb that links the main paper, in which this problem does not exist.

Comment: *strategy* or *strategic undertaking*?

Comment: If *game* is the term used in game theory (and also evidently in other academic disciplines - there is philosophical literature on games, and child psychology is happy to use the word) then why not use it? Are you assuming your audience won't have heard of game theory? A term like "strategic undertaking" might not be any clearer to your audience (it makes me think of warfare) and would take a sizable chunk of your very short blurb.

Comment: If you use a term that you wish to carry a stipulative rather than a default definition, this must be made plain _in every article / section that can reasonably be expected to be read independently_.

Comment: @StuartF - the issue is I don't want the blurb to come off as basic (a lot of people have not great papers just because preprints are a thing) but rather show the quality of the article as best as possible

Comment: If this is just a short blurb, there may not be a good solution. In the actual paper you can explain in the intro what you mean by "game", but a blurb doesn't have room for definitions.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can mention, in addition to American Football, an example of a game commonly studied in game theory. Here is a sampling of them, as listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_in_game_theory). See if any of them would work in your context:

Battle of the sexes, Blotto games, Cake cutting, Centipede game, Chicken (aka hawk-dove), Coordination game, Cournot game, Deadlock, Dictator game, Diner's dilemma, Dollar auction, El Farol bar, Game without a value, Gift-exchange game, Guess 2/3 of the average, Kuhn poker, Matching pennies, Muddy Children Puzzle, Nash bargaining game, Optional prisoner's dilemma, Peace war game, Pirate game, Platonia dilemma, Princess and monster game, Prisoner's dilemma, Public goods, Rock, paper, scissors, Screening game, Signaling game, Stag hunt, Traveler's dilemma, Truel, Trust game, Ultimatum game, Vickrey auction, Volunteer's dilemma, War of attrition.

So, for example, your text might read,

*This method applies for any type of game, from the Nash bargaining game to American football.*

Comment: A little under half of the paper is the example, for which I used NFL. I can't really change that now without *significant* effort